# How do I disable Hot Module Replacement with vue-cli-service serve?

Tags: vue.js, webpack-hmr, vue-cli-3

Whenever I run `vue-cli-service serve` and try to hit the site, I get `Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.` in my browser.

What's causing this error? I don't want HMR enabled.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would anyone not want HMR?

Comment: I'm getting errors when I deploy to production, and the only way I've found to eliminate it was to manually include the HMR plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Set `hotReload` to `false` [in the vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/hot-reload.html#disabling-hot-reload).

Sadly changing the loader options [for vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced) doesn't work.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
        .loader('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          options.hotReload = false
          return options
        })
  }
}
```

Run `vue-cli-service serve --mode=production` which disables HMR, but also does more than that.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting no error, but "[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..." which means in contrary to the documentation. hotReload is still enabled.